# Where should I make API calls in a spring application, in the controller or service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, service, controller

I have a spring application. It exposes an endpoint, which when hit, needs to make an call to some other API. So, where should I make this API call, inside my controller itself or should I do it in the service class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on any Architectural style **(DDD, Microservices, etc)**, we should follow ***separation of concerns***.

Best practice would be to create a **Rest Client** class for the API you want to consume and make all rest calls inside that.

Then you create a **Service** class to call the method consuming the API, performing the operation, data filter, anything you want to do with data.

Next would be to inject your service class *inside the controller* and return the data you just consumed and did some operation on it.

It might not sound well in a small project/feature, but it is the best practice when things get complicated and grow.